# How to post Proactive BOT message in a chat created by MSTeams Graph API by App token

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We created a group chat using MSTeams App Token using Graph APi and it returns the chat id as below,

Request : POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats
Token : App Token

```
{
  "chatType": "group",
  "topic":"SrinithK",
  "members": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('user6e96-xxxx-xxxx-b9cf-84095bdxxxxx')"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('bot19295-xxxx-xxxx-8793-c102f1dbxxxx')"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response :

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#chats/$entity",
    "id": "19:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@thread.v2",
    "topic": "SrinithK",
    "createdDateTime": "2022-01-17T12:28:48.406Z",
    "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2022-01-17T12:28:48.406Z",
    "chatType": "group",
    "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxthread.v2/0?tenantId=xxxxxxx-xxxx-4095-829b-xxxxxxxx",
    "tenantId": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-4095-829b-xxxxxxxx",
    "viewpoint": null,
    "onlineMeetingInfo": null
}
```

On creation of this Chat we are not receiveing any events that contains the ServiceUrls and other data.

We need to post a Bot mesage using Bot token to this chat using BOT REST API v3.

Is there any way we can capture the chat creation event and other data needed for posting the message ?

Answer (score 1):

I've not fully tested it, so this is just a suggestion, but I think there needs to be a first real message sent to the chat to fully initialize it. Try send this initial message using Graph, straight after you create the team, and it should send the initial conversationUpdate to your bot.

Comment: For Teams and channels we are receiving the conversationUpdate. But this not a Team or channel creation . It is chat creation using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Yes I see that, but chats work differently I think. Teams + channels create immediately, but chats I think need the first message to be sent. For instance, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat , specifically where it says "New chats are created in draft state until the user sends the first message." Now, yours is a group chat, not a 1-1, but there's a good chance the same is true nevertheless, which is why I suggested sending an initial test message.

Comment: Chats are also created immediately. Even when we post a message using user access token we are not receiving any events. Do we require _group_ scope in the App. ? At present our app is having _personal_ and _teams_ scope

Comment: Ah, ok - I thought it might be that, was an idea to try. It can possibly be the Group scope, as you suggested - give it a try and see.